# combineLatest with ngrx not updating on changes

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

I have following code:

```
this._loadingStateSubscription = combineLatest(
      select(fromTreeSelector.selectLoadingState),
      select(fromFinanceSelector.selectLoadingState),
      (isTreeLoading, isFinanceLoading) => {
        return isTreeLoading && isFinanceLoading;
      }
    )
      .subscribe(isLoading => this.isLoading = !isLoading);
```

the problem is, I the subscription is not updating on changes. But below I have this code

```
this.store.pipe(select(fromTreeSelector.selectLoadingState))
      .subscribe((isLoading) => {
        // this.isLoading = isLoading;
        console.log("isLoading", isLoading)
      });
    this._loadingStateSubscription = this.store.pipe(select(fromFinanceSelector.selectLoadingState))
      .subscribe((isLoading) => {
        // this.isLoading = isLoading;
        console.log("isLoading", isLoading)
      });
```

and I get a console log message each time it updates.

both selectors looks like this:

```
export const selectLoadingState = (state: AppState) => state.structures.isLoading;
```

any idea on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured out:

```
this.store.select(fromTreeSelector.selectLoadingState),
this.store.select(fromFinanceSelector.selectLoadingState)
```

I have to add `this.store` now it is working.

Comment: It’d be more RxJS 6­‑ish to do `this.store.pipe(select(…))`.

Comment: @gsc nice to know, currenty I am using ngrx 5